# ramdisk.img to ramdisk.cpio.gz

Tags: linux, file-conversion

I have a ramdisk.img file that I would like to change to ramdisk.cpio.gz, can I simply rename the file or do I have to go through the whole archiving process? If I need to go through the archiving process, can someone please tell me the steps required for the process.

Comment: Changing a file extension does not change the contents of the file. Adding .gz to a file name does not magically create a gzip archive. StackOverflow is not the place to learn to use archive software, ask on superuser.com or just check the man page on your computer or do a Google search.

Answer (score 4):

No, `ramdisk.img` is a complete filesystem. You'll need to

1. Mount the .img in a directory, e.g.

   ```
   mkdir /mnt/ramdisk
   mount ramdisk.img /mnt/ramdisk
   ```

   You should now see files in /mnt/ramdisk. (You may need `-o loop` in the mount command - I can never remember when that's needed.)
2. Build a new newc-format cpio archive from the contents of /mnt/ramdisk

   ```
   cd /mnt/ramdisk
   find . -print |cpio -H newc -o |gzip -9 > ~/ramdisk.cpio.gz
   ```
3. Unmount / clean-up

   ```
   umount /mnt/ramdisk
   rm -rf /mnt/ramdisk
   ```

This is all off the top of my head so may contain silly errors. Hope it works!

Comment: Do I need to mount the ramdisk? The ramdisk is going to be used for an android platform

Comment: If the ramdisk.img is a filesystem image then you'll need to read the files off it somehow and mounting it is going to be the easiest way to do that - it's only temporary to access the files. I don't know if there's anything specific you'd need to do for Android though.

Comment: I ended up not needing to archive the file, but I did try your method and ran into the problem needing to know the file system type

Comment: Oh, OK - sorry about that. You can usually tell by `file ramdisk.img`, although if that works it's likely mount could autodetect it too. However from Googling now it's possible we mislead you: [apparently some Android ramdisk.imgs really are ramdisk.cpio.gzs](http://discuz-android.blogspot.com/2008/01/step-by-step-to-createmodify-ramdiskimg.html) :-/ Sorry if that was the case - I'd no idea Android worked like that. ramdisk.img is usually an ext2 (or romfs I think) filesystem image.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to replace an initrd image, with an initramfs archive. There is a script in the kernel sources to do the second part. It is in `scripts/gen_initramfs_list.sh.` You might want to read [this](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt).